# Webview Android does'nt load whole content from a large html file

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a very large html [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3y9wjsxxymhou52/test.html?dl=0)(around 10k lines of only text). When I use Webview to load this html content, it shows only around few hundreds and remaining space is blank(white space). Can someone help me with this issue? Thank You.
Following is my code:

```
WebView mWebView;
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");//test.html in assets folder
```

I also try with webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null) or webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null) but it does'nt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found solution for my issue with Webview. The reason Webview can't display whole content of html file because the html is not well constructed, some html tag like `<abc@.com>` will not be read by Webview. So I convert content to correct html form then it works.